# How can I trick a Fastgate modem to think I'm operating locally?

Tags: router, credentials

Fastweb provides Fastgate RTV1907VW-D228 which somehow allows access to the web GUI only from the local network.

To explain: if I connect to a computer in the home network using TeamViewer, I can load the login page, I can enter the username and password (they are correct) and click, but the login will be refused with "wrong password". If I ask a person sitting at the computer to enter the data, while I'm watching via TeamViewer, the login does work.

Similarly, I cannot have the login accepted when I use a SSH tunnel from my computer to a server in the home network, to the router (`ssh home.dydns -L 10000:192.168.1.1:80` where the SSH server is within the home network).

How can I trick the modem to think I'm a real local user?

Edit:

I know I'm using the correct credentials: I typed the password in the username field to check I was typing correctly then I cut and pasted, as alternative to directly typing in the password field.

The credentials are good.

Comment: You have the wrong password or a minor gotcha like numlock or capslock means you are not entering what you think you are. If you are using teamviewer to use a web browser then it is not possible for a modem to determine if you or a person local to the computer entered it.

Comment: @davidgo I don't think so: I typed the password in the username field to check I was typing correctly then I cut and pasted, as alternative to normal typing in the password field.

Comment: AFAIK there is no mechanism that exists in teamviewer or web browsers which intercepts the data stream from teamviewer - Its a very long stretch - particularly as you have copy and pasted, but could something be the way teamviewer is presenting the keybiard input - can you get the password changed to one without special characters and see if that solves the pronlblem.